# Lost docker container after restarting EC2 instance

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2

I was running a python script in EC2 within Docker container. I think the EC2 crashed because of 'Out of memory'. So I had to restart the EC2 else, couldn't get into EC2. After restarting I couldn't find my docker container. Any idea how to restore the docker?
I tried

> docker ps -a

It returned nothing. Unable to check logs as well. 
Also when I checked inside /var/lib/docker/volumes I only see a .db file. 
/var/lib/docker/
Any leads on how to recover or How to AVOID this situation in the future?

Comment: I'd repeat the `docker run` command you originally used to start the container, and not worry too much about this case.  If it works better for your workflow (say, a userdata script actually launches the container) delete and recreate the instance.

Comment: If you previously run the container with the `--rm` flag e.g. `docker run --rm -it ...` then when you exit the container or when docker or the VM restart, the container will be deleted automatically.

Comment: Thanks @NguyenLamPhuc , I did used the '-rm' flag. Thanks for the pro tip!

Answer (score 1):

I also faced similar kind of issue like instance got stopped due to some issues. So after a small research found that actually the containers didnt delete instead they stopped(Exited). So you would be able to see if you type `docker ps -a` command. Then you have to start the containers.

Answer (score 0):

try to see if you can see the container by `docker ps -a`
if you can see the containers listed and the status, if the status is stopped just start is by `docker container start`
And if you have a Apache server running inside the docker don't forget to restart it!